# auto-start java app at windows 8.1 login

Tags: java, powershell, system-tray, autostart

I have a java app that I want to auto-start at user login on a clients Windows 8.1 box.

I have created an executable jar on my Windows 8.1 box.

I have converted the jar to a Windows executable via **Launch4j**.

I have generated a Windows setup executable containing the app and a *jre* via Inno Setup Script.

I have downloaded the setup executable to the client Windows 8.1 box.

I have run the setup executable on the client box.

In the install directory on the client machine, I have run a **powershell** ps1 file
that successfully creates a shortcut (a `.lnk` file) to my app in the Windows 8.1 directory structure at:

```
C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\mycompanyname
```

The contents of my powershell ps1 file are:

```
powershell Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned

$TargetFile = "C:\Program Files (x86)\mycompanyname\myexecutablename.exe"
$ShortcutFile = "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\mycompanyname\mylinkname.lnk"
$WScriptShell = New-Object -ComObject WScript.Shell
$Shortcut = $WScriptShell.CreateShortcut($ShortcutFile)
$Shortcut.TargetPath = $TargetFile
$Shortcut.Save()
"$TargetFile -NoLog -NoExit"
```

My reason for running powershell is to create the shortcut link to my app programmatically, rather than have my client user wade through a large number of Windows UI pages.

When I right click on the shortcut and run it as administrator, my app icon appears in the SystemTray as expected.  I can right click on the icon and select my various options, and all works well.

However, when I log out, and then log back in, my app icon does not appear in the SystemTray.

How do I get my app icon to appear in the SystemTray after I log out and then log back in?

At this time I am guessing that my **powershell** ps1 needs to not only create and save my shortcut, but also to set things up such that the app auto-starts at user login.

The end goal is to have my app icon appear in the SystemTray after a user logs in to the Windows 8.1 box, much in the same manner that the app icons for `WebRoot, Norton Security Suite, etc., do.`

Help, please.

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://www.howtogeek.com/208224/how-to-add-programs-files-and-folders-to-system-startup-in-windows-8.1/)

Comment: Are Your sure not think about Windows Service (like i.e. Tomcat). Service can be running all the time, when user is logged may have contact via System Tray.

Answer (score 1):

I would use the Registry and the `Run` key.

More details [seen here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376977(v=vs.85).aspx)

Sample.reg shown below.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run]
"MyApplication"="C:\\Program Files\\MyApplication\\1234567.exe"
```

Comment: This solution works well for me.  Thank You!  The only problem left to solve is:  When the application runs, it displays a window of some sort (maybe a java console window, I'm not sure).  Is there a way to auto-minimize or auto-hide the window?

Comment: The following command works well at the Windows 8.1 command line:   'start /min /D c:\"program files (x86)"\mycompanyname myappname.exe' however it fails to work in the registry at HKCU\software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run.

Comment: The ultimate answer to auto-start my app at user login time without any annoying window flash is to run it from HKCU:software/Microsoft/Windows/CurrentVersion/Run as wscript.exe c:"program files (x86)"\mycompanyname\invisible.vbs C:\"program files (x86)"\mycompanyname\startup.bat where invisible.vbs looks like CreateObject("Wscript.Shell").Run """" & WScript.Arguments(0) & """", 0, False

Comment: Apologies for the late reply, I've looked up this behavior and found the registry is similar to CMD line.  Try `cmd /c start /min /D c:\"program files (x86)"\mycompanyname myappname.exe`  Also: If my answer helped, please consider marking it helpful.